# Can't set custom resolution in ubuntu in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution, xrandr

I have resolution 2520:1680 (3:2). This resolution is not standard, so i can’t set it through the settings Try change it using xrandr, but it doesn't work (i got exception)

**I try this**

gtf 2520 1680 60

2520x1680 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 104.28 kHz; pclk: 361.23 MHz
Modeline "2520x1680_60.00" 361.23 2520 2712 2992 3464 1680 1681 1684 1738 -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --newmode "2520x1680_60.00" 361.23 2520 2712 2992 3464 1680 1681 1684 1738 -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "2520x1680_60.00"

xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode "2520x1680_60.00"

**And get this:**

X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request: 139 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request: 7 (RRSetScreenSize)
Serial number of failed request: 22
Current serial number in output stream: 23

Comment: you're using wayland, not xorg, so xrandr won't work to change resolution. that's why your only display is "XWAYLAND0"- it's a way for wayland to be compatible with xorg.